# joining and possible sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `user`, 'user_friends' and 'blog_post'

The schema is similar to the following:

```
user
id    |   username
-------------------
1     |   jim
-------------------
2     |   mary
-------------------
3     |   george
-------------------
4     |   julie



user_friends
user_id   |  friend_id
----------------------
1         |    2
----------------------
2         |    3
----------------------
2         |    4


blog_posts
id    |   title    |   user_id
------------------------------
1     |  test_1    |  1
------------------------------
2     |  test_2    |  2
------------------------------
3     |  test_3    |  3
------------------------------
4     |  test_4    |  4
```

Ok, so you can see each user has made a blog post. Users have 'friends'. What I'm looking to do, is display each users friends blog posts.

So, If I'd like to see Jims friends posts, it should show mary's post of test_2. If I want to see mary's friends posts, it should show george and julie's posts of test_3 and test_4

Is there an easy way of doing this? Could I use sub-selects?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a sub-selection.
Something like this should work :

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE user_id in 
(SELECT friend_id FROM user_friend WHERE user_id=1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I knew i was on the right track! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Could be as simple as that (variant with a JOIN):

```
SELECT bp.*
FROM   user_friends uf
JOIN   blob_posts bp ON bp.user_id = uf.friend_id
WHERE  uf.user_id = my_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From blog_posts
Where user_id in
    (Select friend_id
    From user_friends
    where user_id = 1);
```

the number at the end can be whatever user ID you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE user_id IN (
SELECT friend_id FROM user_friends WHERE user_id = X)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bp.* 
FROM blog_posts bp
INNER JOIN user_friends uf ON bp.user_id = uf.friend_id
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = uf.user_id
WHERE u.username = "jim"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this request:

```
SELECT bp.title
FROM blog_posts bp
JOIN user_friends uf ON (bp.user_id = uf.friend_id)
WHERE uf.user_id = 1;
```